# Rendering lots of similar but not identical meshes on scene

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

We have 1 geometry that gets attached to every mesh in our scene.

```
var geometry = new three.PlaneGeometry(1, 1, 1, 1),
```

Everything has a texture that we generate and cache to create a new material and a mesh for each object.

```
this.material = new three.MeshLambertMaterial({
    transparent: true,
    emissive: 0xffffff
});
// get the cached texture
this.material.map = this.getTexture(this.attributes);
this.shape = new three.Mesh(geometry, this.material);
```

Afterwards we add these shapes into various Object3Ds in order to move large groups of shapes around.

This all works great on nicer devices and up to 5000 circles, but then our framerate starts to drop. On weaker devices this is dramatically slower even with say 100 meshes. We know that merging geometries can speed things up; however, we only have a single geometry that is shared. Is it possible to merge meshes? Does that even make sense? Note: These shapes are interactive (movable/clickable). What are our options?

Other notes:
We are using Ejecta on mobile devices, which is great at low mesh counts, but not so great after 100 meshes. I don't think its Ejecta's fault, but rather our lack of knowledge about how to optimize! Also even on desktop our app has some CPU usage amount that we find suspicious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out! We went from being able to render 5k things at 60fps to 100k things at approx 40fps.

We followed what most people are saying out there about merging meshes, but it took some experimentation to really understand what was happening and getting multiple textures/materials to work.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    // creates a mesh from the geometry and material from the question and returns an object
    circle = ourCircleFactory.create(); 
    circle.shape.updateMatrix();
    sceneGeometry.merge(circle.shape.geometry, circle.shape.matrix, circle.cachedMaterialIndex);
}
var finalMesh = new three.Mesh(sceneGeometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(cachedMaterials));
scene.add(finalMesh);
```

That code will create 1 geometry per cached material. `cachedMaterialIndex` is something we created to cache textures and indicate which material to use.

It is likely that this code will create 1 geometry per combination of material and geometry. EG: if you have 5 geometries and they are interchangeable with 5 materials then you will get 25 geometries. It seems that it doesn't matter how many objects you have on screen. Note: we were getting 15fps with 5000 geometries so I think this is a fairly cheap solution.